# Dcount A Parameterised Query Access

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

Beginner at access, so sorry if this is a question that has been asked before (I've searched for ages, so maybe im searching for the wrong thing?). Anyway, in my database I have a form that is used to submit records, and a query that checks for double bookings (it shows all records that overlap with the inputted dates). I have created a 'submit record' button on the form, and all I am trying to do is validate that there are no double bookings by running the double booking query and checking if there are no records.

I have tried using a Dcount function for this, however I cannot seem to find how to run the query as it has parameters (I need to pass the inputs of the form to the query). I am unsure if this is the most efficient way to check for double bookings, but I just need a solution what works at the moment :P. This is my current code, which obviously doesnt work as the sql query requires parameters:

```
If DCount("*","Double Booked")=0 Then ...
```

(Where 'Double Booked' is the name of my query in the database)

Sorry if I was unclear, thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is the double booked query code:

```
SELECT *
FROM Booking
WHERE (

([Your VanID] = [Booking].[VanID])

AND (

( ([Your Collection Date] >= [Booking].[Collection date]) AND ([Your Collection Date] <= [Booking].[Return date]))

OR ([Your Return Date] >= [Booking].[Collection date]) AND ([Your Return Date] <= [Booking].[Return date])

OR (([Your Collection Date] <= [Booking].[Collection date]) AND ([Your Return Date] >= [Booking].[Return date]))

)

);
```

Comment: Done, ive edited the original post

Comment: Thanks.  Just to confirm, the query has 3 parameters named `[Your VanID]`, `[Your Collection Date]`, and `[Your Return Date]` and you have 3 form controls you will use to supply the parameter values.  Is that correct?  If so, are those controls on the same form which contains that "submit" button?

Comment: Yes, the query has those 3 parameters, and within my form I have 3 fields that I want to use the values from when I run the query. The submit button is on the same form as the 3 fields aswell

Comment: Good.  I see Andre updated his answer, so you should be OK as long as you understand that `EVal_Params` function is not usable for your query.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused - why is the Eval_Params function unusable? Should I be using the method under the edit?

Comment: I didn't mean unusable in every situation, just that it's not useful for your specific query.  The procedure expects the parameters to be form controls ... similar to  `Forms!YourForm!YourTextBox`, but yours are simply plain named parameters such as `[Your VanID]`, etc.  You could revise the query to use `Forms!YourForm!YourTextBox` style parameters, and then `Eval_Params()` could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to know **if** there are double bookings (not how many), `DCount` is unnecessary. Opening a recordset is enough.

Queries with form fields as parameters run fine when opened directly, or as a RecordSource, but not when opened in VBA.

To be able to do this, I have this function in a public module:

```vb
Public Sub EVal_Params(QD As DAO.QueryDef)

On Error GoTo EVal_Params_Err

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim par As DAO.Parameter

    For i = 0 To QD.Parameters.Count - 1
        Set par = QD.Parameters(i)
        ' This is the key line: Eval "evaluates" the form field and gets the value
        par.Value = Eval(par.Name)
    Next i

EVal_Params_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub

EVal_Params_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Runtime-Error " & Err.Number & " in EVal_Params"
    Resume EVal_Params_Exit

End Sub
```

With that you can open a recordset on the query, and its `.EOF` property will tell you whether there are double bookings:

```vb
Dim DB As DAO.Database
Dim QD As DAO.QueryDef
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset

Set DB = CurrentDb

Set QD = DB.QueryDefs("Double Booked")
' Get form field values into query parameters
Call EVal_Params(QD)
Set RS = QD.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
If RS.EOF Then
    ' no doubles
Else
    ' there are double bookings
End If
RS.Close
```

**Edit**

If the query parameters are not references to form controls, but "normal" named parameters, you'd do instead:

```vb
Set QD = DB.QueryDefs("Double Booked")
QD.Parameters("Your VanID") = someValue
QD.Parameters("Your Collection Date") = someOtherValue
Set RS = QD.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your very detailed reply - as this is the only place in the database that I need to test for double bookings, can I just write the Eval_Params function above in a public Sub?

Comment: @TheInfernalCow: I have it in a "library" module with other standard functions, but you can also put it into the form module if it's only used there. Make it a `Private Sub` then.